# Codeigniter - Reservation Function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've been trying to finish my reservation function, and some of you may even already know me since I've been trying to ask many questions here for consecutive days regarding this function. I've been trying to create a reservation function, wherein users can reserve for the basketball court any date they would like to. An admin will approve the reservation, because sometimes, the courts are used by the village administrators therefore it cannot be used. So in approving, there will be a validation to check whether that date has already been taken, and if it is taken, then it will not be approved. Here's my database table.

[image]

So the reservation_start and reservation_end numbers stand for their respective hours, 6 as 6:00 PM, 7 as 7:00 PM, and so on. What I did was create a model to check whether a slot was already taken, and I created an array which serves as switches whenever an hour was taken. I also used the "group_by" query in order to group my reservation dates into one, so that the switches will be reset whenever there is a different date. My problem is that the switches are carried over into the other dates. In the example above, 02/26/2017 has been reserved from 7:00 PM to 10:00 PM. This means that the switches will be "on" from 7 until 9(in order for 10:00 PM as the start time to be still reserved). Then, on March 3, the switches are being carried over, which means that I cannot reserve them since it reads that 7:00 has been taken, therefore I cannot reserve from 6:00 to 8:00 PM.

Here's the code.

```
function checkexisting_reserve_courtone()
{
    $checkresult = $this->db->select('*')->from('courtone_reservation')->where('reservation_status', 1)->group_by('reservation_date')->get();
    $resultreserve = $checkresult->result();

    $tdX = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    foreach($resultreserve as $result)
    {

        while($result->reservation_start < $result->reservation_end)
        {
            $tdX[$result->reservation_start] = 1;
            $result->reservation_start++;
        }
    }

    foreach($resultreserve as $result)
    {
        $reserveactualend = $result->reservation_end - 1;
        if($tdX[$result->reservation_start] == 1 || $tdX[$reserveactualend] == 1) 
        {
            return FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Is there a get-around here? Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: So, it doesn't matter that court has already been booked, only that it's already been booked by the village administrators?

Comment: Yes, which means that the users can have overlapping reservations at first (pending) , but the admin will have to last call on who to approve first. User A can book 02/26/2017 at 6:00 PM - 9:00 PM, and User B can also do it. However, the admin cannot approve both and should only choose one.

Comment: Hm. I'd suggest you see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query#